# ElasticSearch using python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am using python to import file into `ElasticSearch`. Simple data I can Import but facing issue when there is combination of letters and numbers as well special characters.

I am using below script:

```
from datetime import datetime
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import os

es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])

f = open("E:\\ElasticSearch\\test.txt",'r')

fulldata = f.readlines()
f.close()
del fulldata[0]

for line in fulldata:
  array = line.split(",")
  guid = array[0]
  senderid = array[1]
  campaign = array[2]

  json_body = "{\"guid\" : \""+ guid+"\", \"senderid\" : \""+ senderid+"\", \"campaign\" : "+ str(campaign)+"}}"

  print json_body
  res = es.index(index="mytest", doc_type="msg", id=guid, body=json_body)
```

test.txt file contain data like

```
guid    senderid campaign
26fac319-604b-11e5-b1fe,003001,Weekday_EGV_21Sept_4pm_Round2_Tier1_Part1,
```

I am getting error like

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: TransportError<400, u"MapperParsingException [failed to parse ]; nested: JsonParseException [Unrecognized token 'Weekday_EGV_21Sept_4pm_Round2_Tired1_Part1' : was excepting ('true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: [B@b5685ce; line: 1, column:95}}; ")
```

Comment: Can you please **post your code** instead of a _picture_ of your code?

Comment: from datetime import datetime
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import os
es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])

f = open("E:\\ElasticSearch\\test.txt",'r')

fulldata = f.readlines()
f.close()
del fulldata[0]

for line in fulldata:
 array = line.split(",")
 guid = array[0]
 senderid = array[1]
 campaign = array[2]
  
 json_body = "{\"guid\" : \""+ guid+"\", \"senderid\" : \""+ senderid+"\", \"campaign\" : "+ str(campaign)+"}}"
  
 print json_body
 res = es.index(index="mytest", doc_type="msg", id=guid, body=json_body)

Comment: Please edit that into your question itself instead of posting it as a comment.

Comment: Here is the img you original included in your code http://i.stack.imgur.com/eKNxH.png

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code it appears there are 2 errors with your JSON.  In it's original for it produces the follwoing string:

```
{"guid" : "26fac319-604b-11e5-b1fe", "senderid" : "003001", "campaign" : Weekday_EGV_21Sept_4pm_Round2_Tier1_Part1}}
```

You are missing quotes around that final field value of `campaign` and you have an extra `}` at the end.  If you make the following change:

```
json_body = "{\"guid\" : \""+ guid+"\", \"senderid\" : \""+ senderid+"\", \"campaign\" : \""+ str(campaign)+"\"}"
```

it should resolve the JsonParseException error.

Comment: I found another bug in your json code, can you see if that helps?